# Blockchain Questions

Tags: hyperledger, blockchain, ethereum, bigchaindb, distributed-apps

I am currently developing a thesis project for the Master of Computer Engineering. The project is being developed in a business environment and consists on the creation of an abstract module based on the concept of blockchain, so it is possible to integrate it into several company products. In the course of my research a number of questions have arisen:

- In blockchain concept there are several nodes that share a ledger, in which each node participates in the network (inserting data in the ledger and validating this data). Does it make sense that only 1 node enter data and the other nodes just serve the consensus mechanism? If this makes no sense, what are the alternatives?
- It makes sense to have a ledger common to all customers that contain data in this ledger, and is this ledger not distributed by these customers, but by other entities that are responsible for maintaining the ledger and serving the consensus mechanism?
- Can any node read the ledger data? Do these restrictions depend only on technology?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In blockchain concept there are several nodes that share a ledger, in which each node participates in the network (inserting data in the ledger and validating this data). Does it make sense that only 1 node enter data and the other nodes just serve the consensus mechanism? If this makes no sense, what are the alternatives?

> Yes it’s possible. Not every participating node has to be a mining node. You have basically 2 types of nodes in the network that is mining nodes and transactional nodes.

It makes sense to have a ledger common to all customers that contain data in this ledger, and is this ledger not distributed by these customers, but by other entities that are responsible for maintaining the ledger and serving the consensus mechanism?

> don’t understand this question. Please put it in a better way

Can any node read the ledger data? Do these restrictions depend only on technology?

> Any node participating can read the data. Infact anyone in the world can read the ledger without node I.e., through Block explorers like etherscan